# In Python, how to log full module path, class and function name?

Tags: python, python-logging

In Python, how can I log the full module path, class and function name? For example:

**src/my_package/my_module.py**

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s | ??? | %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

class MyClass:
    def my_function(self):
        logging.debug('msg')
```

**Expected Output**

```
DEBUG | my_package.my_module.MyClass.my_function | msg
```

I am aware of the `%(pathname)s` specifier, which is not what I want.

Comment: The `LogRecord` where this data is picked from only has the path & line number. Modules & classes are not captured there: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a workaround that is good enough for my use case:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s | %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

class MyClass:
    def my_function(self):
        log_path = f'{__name__}.{MyClass.__name__}.{MyClass.my_function.__name__}'

        logging.debug(f'{log_path} | msg')
```

The drawback is that I have to build the `log_path` at the beginning of every function I want to log in and pass it as part of the message.