# Why does not Python LogRecord capture full (importable) module name

Tags: python, logging

Python logging formatter provides several [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) about the log site. While `pathname` (absolute path of the file) is comprehensive, it maybe more noisy. The `module` attribute only give the name of the file without extension (if `my_package.sub_package.my_module` is a fully importable module spec, then it gives only `my_module`).

A [comment on SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122100/in-python-how-to-log-full-module-path-class-and-function-name#comment116902216_66122100) mentions that module is not captured(as of Feb 2021). Why is this so, since module is quite useful in some occasions? Are there any technical/API design concerns?

Comment: Re. Your comment - don't try and "optimise" things by having a logger only in one place - the system is designed to create loggers as singletons by name wherever they're needed. Use the recommended approach - it's recommended for a reason.

Comment: @VinaySajip For a perspective, what would the downside of including module in the LogRecord? That seems to simplify the usage; does it introduce performance cost and/or implementation complexity?

Comment: The way it currently works is deemed simple/performant enough. It doesn't _appear_ to have led to performance or implementation complexity issues in the many years that it's been like this ...

Comment: I was trying to understand the reason for the recommendation. I am still not very clear on the mechanics of it. For instance, what would be the downside implication of defining in one place and importing?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [recommended approach](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial) of naming your loggers with `__name__`, then the `LogRecord`'s `name` attribute will be the module, and you won't need to use the `module` attribute of the record.

Comment: this perspective is helpful. But this requires importing and initialing logging in each module(import logging; logger =.. ), say, instead of defining in one place and import the logger (from util import logger) . The later approach looks more convenient to me (but I would loose the module info, unless I change the name explicitly)